# Basic jQuery AJAX performance Inquiry

Tags: javascript, jquery

When doing ajax requests using jQuery's ajax() function I never use any parameters other than "data" in the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

But I was wondering if keeping the other 2 parameters (textStatus, jqXHR) in that function will have any performance impact:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert(data);
}
```

I am not doing anything with "textStatus" and "jqXHR", but if I kept them there will there be any performance decrease (even a little)?

Comment: If you aren't using them, don't include them. It saves bytes, too.

Comment: Check out the source -https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a little bit, but nothing noticeable considering you're not referencing them - no memory lookups will have to be performed.

If you're doing millions of AJAX calls a second, you might see a delay, but how on Earth you can do a million AJAX requests a second I don't know.